# Django Python Testing: How do I assert that some exception happened and was handled

Tags: python, django, testing, testcase, assertraises

I'm trying to test a Django view using the client post method.

Inside the view I catch an exception and return a 500 response

My test that checks the 500 response passes however I would also now like to test what actual Exception class was raised during the view call.

Is there a way to do that?

I've tried self.assertRaises(SpecificException) as a context manager but since it is already handled and caught, it won't do what I'm looking for:

```
with self.assertRaises(SpecificException):
    response = self.client.post(
        path=reverse("stock:getstockinvt"),
        data={'product_id': 1},
        content_type='application/json'
    )
```

If this can't be done then so be it, I am just wondering if this can.

The alternative is to unit test the function that raises the exception.

Comment: Log the handled exception in the exception handler and use `AssertLogs`?

Comment: Feels like you're testing at the wrong level. Any test that involves the test client should be looking at the behaviour of the view as a whole, without regard to how it works internally. If you're interested in a specific element of that internal behaviour, you should test that separately - perhaps by extracting that logic into a separate class/function that you can call specifically.

Comment: @nigel222 I will try that, I may not use it as a final solution as I may not want to put a logger there, but thanks anyway

Comment: @DanielRoseman I agree and think this is the best way to do it, i.e. isolate the tests, I guess my curiosity overcame me